# Is the WHILE loop needed?

Tags: php, arrays, database, while-loop

When I need to get an array from the database, in this case a list of all user ids with a Gold sub, but is the while loop really needed, I feel like I'm looping through an array to make an identical array? but I don't understand how to just use the original array I'm looping through? if that make any sense?

Here is the code of what I'm talking about. . .

```
 <?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT logby FROM users WHERE sub=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $subtype);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $logby[] = $row["logby"];
    }
    $logby = implode(",", $logby);
    echo $logby;
?>
```

I want to better understand this

Comment: If you want an array of rows, use [`fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_all) instead of `fetch_assoc`. `$row["logby"]` is going to be missing, by the way. There's no column named that in your query.

Comment: You could do all the operations in the loop as well. `$logby .= $row["logby"] . ',';` then either `rtrim` the `,` after loop, or conditionally add the `,` only if it is not the last record... another solution could be `group_concat` in mysql but that depends on your `group_concat` limit size and how large your data return is.

Comment: @ceejayoz I still don't get it, so I would still need to use a while loop even when using fetch all? or not? can you show me how it would look using fetch all without the while loop?

Comment: FWIW, you would be much better off with PDO. There is no need to use the old mysqli extension unless you are stuck with some legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

No, a `while` loop is seldom needed. The purpose of a while loop is to let the programmer execute something in a loop when the number of iterations is indeterminate.

In this case, you can simply fetch all records into an array in a single go, e.g. using `fetch_all()` + `array_column()`, or using a `foreach` loop. The number of iterations is known already because all rows are in PHP memory after being fetched with `get_result`. There is the unbuffered mode in mysqli that would mean you don't know the number of rows, but it's rarely used.